# Объясните паттерн на c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Перечитал разные статьи в интернете, пошарил в книгах, но так и не нашел четкого объяснения и примеров паттернов на c++.

Comment: Если вы раньше ни разу не сталкивались с паттернами, то советую эту книгу для начала http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31079082/

Answer (score 6):

1. Паттерны бывают не только на c++, они универсальны для всего программирования.
2. Паттерны позволяют решать типовые задачи стандартными методами, о которых большинство опытных программистов ознакомлено, что повышает качество сопровождения кода - написать может один, а поддерживать - другой.
3. Паттерны позволяют во время проектирования программы использовать их сленговые названия, а не "эээ.... нуу, как Петрович в прошлом году делал".
4. Их применение может сократить время на проектирование, за счет сокращения количества велосипедов.
5. Паттерны позволяют обойти опасные, а также трудные для понимания места, потому как возможные проблемы уже ранее были исследованы разработчиками паттернов, опубликованы и изучены.

Comment: Если быть точным, то паттерны не универсальны, но они применимы, как правило, на некотором наборе языков, а не только на одном. Не удивлюсь, правда, что некоторые паттерны присущи только одним языкам.